# Conflicting Nginx Rewrite Rules

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Looking for some help with Nginx rewrite rules. I am running Wordpress and MailWizz on the same server. Wordpress is installed in the root and MailWizz is installed in root/mw.

The WordPress rewrite rules are:

```
  ## WordPress Perm links config ##               
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
 
    ## Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
 
    ## Deal with sitemap wordpress plugin urls ##
    rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml$ "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2" last;
    rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml\.gz$ "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2;zip=true" last;
    rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.html$ "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2;html=true" last;
    rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.html.gz$ "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2;html=true;zip=true" last;
 
    # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }
```

And the MailWizz rewrite rules are:

```
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite mw/customer/.* /mw/customer/index.php;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite mw/backend/.* /mw/backend/index.php;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite mw/api/.* /mw/api/index.php;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /mw/index.php;
    }
```

Whenever I try to include the WordPress rules with the MailWizz rules it causes problems with WordPress permalinks. So I'm looking for a way to make the two co-exist. Its primarily the MailWizz rules that break WordPress, MailWizz continues to work ok.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping the MailWizz rules inside a `location /mw { ... }` block

Comment: When I do that it fixes WordPress, but it breaks MailWizz. The MailWizz URL looks correct, but I get a 404.

Comment: Your suggestion got me thinking about the fact that MW is in a subfolder and the IF statement only refers to ```$request_filename``` So I didn't put MW in its own location block, and instead changed it ```/mw/$request_filename``` and removed the last IF statement that rewrites root requests to ```/mw/index.php```. Thanks for the tip!